# How to decrpyt a string received from a server?

Tags: java, string, sockets, encryption

I am creating an echo server/client with encryption. Basically what I want the program to do is:

1. the user types a string in the client
2. the client encrypts the string
3. the client sends the encrypted string to the server
4. the server receives the string
5. the server sends the string back to the client
6. the client receives the string
7. the client decrypts the string
8. the client displays the decrypted string

My problem is that when the client tries to decrypt the string received from the server it fails and throws me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length
must be multiple of 8 when decrypting with padded cipher
        at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:936)
        at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:847)
        at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DESCipher.java:314)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2202)
        at EnClient.decrypt(EnClient.java:100)
        at EnClient.main(EnClient.java:85)
```

I have tried decrypting the string before sending it to the server and then it works fine so this definitely has something to do with the string going through the socket to the server and back. And I also noticed that the error I get commonly happens when there is some sort of problem with the padding of the encrypted string. Apart from that info I was able to gather I don't know what to do or how to fix this. So I need help from you. First of all please tell me if my assumptions are correct or not and your advice on how to fix this.

The client code:

```java
c1 = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
String userInput;
while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
    byte[] eui = encrypt(userInput);
    System.out.println(eui);
    System.out.println(decrypt(eui));
    out.println(eui.toString());
    byte[] ein = in.readLine().getBytes();
    String din = decrypt(ein);
    System.out.println(din);
}
...
private static String decrypt(byte[] encryptionBytes) throws Exception{
    c1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, k);
    byte[] recoveredBytes = c1.doFinal(encryptionBytes);
    String recovered = new String(recoveredBytes);
    return recovered;
}

private static byte[] encrypt(String input) throws Exception {
    c1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, k);
    byte[] ib = input.getBytes();
    return c1.doFinal(ib);
}
```

The server code:

```java
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    out.println(inputLine);
}
```

I'm thinking that I could fix this by comparing the received string with the original encrypted string and if they match then just decrypting the original string, but that seems like a program that simply encrypts and decrypts a string with extra steps and I don't want that. I want the client to decrypt a string received directly from the server.

Anyway, any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I replaced this:

```java
...
byte[] eui = encrypt(userInput);
System.out.println(eui);
System.out.println(decrypt(eui));
out.println(eui.toString());
byte[] ein = in.readLine().getBytes();
String din = decrypt(ein);
System.out.println(din);
...
```

with this:

```java
...
byte[] eui = encrypt(userInput);
String b64eui = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(eui);
out.println(b64eui);
byte[] ein = Base64.getDecoder().decode(in.readLine().getBytes());
String din = decrypt(ein);
System.out.println("echo: " + din);
...
```

Comment: `eui.toString()` doesn't do what you think it does. It doesn't do anything useful. Also, you are mixing up byte-oriented and character-oriented IO. For a beginner this can be very complicated. I think the easiest solution is to continue using character-oriented IO but encode your `byte[]` to a string using the Base64 class prior to sending over the socket. Remember to decode the string back to a `byte[]` before decrypting.

Answer (score 0):

`out.println` appends newline character (`\n`)

Maybe it makes the encrypted array of bytes have wrong length.

Comment: The `readLine()` will remove the newline character that was added by `println()`.